# Is this a safe method of securing pages on my site

Tags: php, security

I have a login script that does a lookup in the db on the user based on the username and password provided at login and then a cookie is created that stores an encrypted string in the following way:

```
$securesession = $username.'[:#:]'.$dbactype.'[#]'.$dbperson.'[#]'.time().'[#]'.$expiretime.'[#]'.$useragent.'[#]'.$ipaddress.'[#]'.$masterkey;
$securesession = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $securesession, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
setcookie("_session_sitename", $securesession, $expiretime, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE);
```

Some details about the user and the session are stored as well as the UA string and IP, the site then has a $masterkey which is a complex string of random characters inc. special characters and there is a $key defined globally which is used to encrypt and decrypt the cookie.

Subsequent requests for pages if the `$_COOKIE['_session_sitename']` exists are then validated by decoding this cookie, exploding it by the delimiter `[#]` and verifying that the IP and useragent exploded from the decoded cookie match the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` & `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` as well as the site `$masterkey`.

The question is, is this level of "security" enough or should I think about adding additional layers?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and belongs on [security.se]

Comment: This doesn't appear to me more secure than having a traditional, random session ID - it seems rather *less* secure. All the information you are using to prevent session hijacking (user agent, IP [although that may get you in trouble with some clients because it's not always constant]) you can and should store on server side only, and compare them with the actual values you're getting from the client. No point sending that stuff to the client side, encrypted or not

Comment: @kai - Seems rather complicated to achieve nothing. Just use a session ID and store on the server the rest of the details. Upon request look up the session ID - check IP address, expiry time etc

Comment: @EdHeal + Pekka - OK cool, thanks! I will rewrite the code so the data is stored into for example $_SESSION['_session_data'] instead of client side. The previous solution held the session details in our DB and so a read operation was required for every page request requiring authentication, ultimately I am just trying to reduce the number of DB requests without compromising security as not every page requires a database read, the end goal will be to have a read operation on login. And then only when data is required or changed from/within the DB. Very much appreciate your insight - Thank you!

Comment: @kai - DB access is cheap. If you hit performance problems ensure you have the appropriate indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments above - I will rewrite the code so the data is stored into a session ID for example `$_SESSION['_session_data']` instead of client side in a cookie. This way only the session token is stored client side, thus adding an additional layer of security.

Thanks to EdHeal & Pekka for their input in comments!